# Z-Buffer rendering objects

Tags: java, opengl

I did a cicle to render some 'blocks' (Java), but from one side is like this: [image]

But on the other side is correct: [image]

I have this activated:

```
    GL11.glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    GL11.glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: did you actually allocate a depth buffer on startup?

Comment: How many bits did you give your depth buffer when you chose your pixel format? If you cannot answer that question, then you probably don't have a depth buffer.

Comment: What ratchet freak and Andon M. Coleman are trying to tell you is, that when creating the window onto which you draw with OpenGL you must actually allocate a depth buffer component for it, otherwise there's nothing the OpenGL depth testing can work with.